# Id like to use my return value from a selection method as the value in my main function

Tags: python, methods, return-value, subclass

I want to use the odds assigned to subclasses in the callplay() function on the line "result =" etc... having a hard time with the syntax

```
def phil_choice():
    print('1) Balanced\n2) Run Heavy\n3) Pass Heavy')
    philo_choice = input('Select a coaching style:  ')
    if philo_choice == '1':
        print('')
        print('You have selected a balanced strategy')
        return balanced
    elif philo_choice == '2':
        print('')
        print('You have selected a run heavy strategy')
        return hevrun
    elif philo_choice == '3':
        print('')
        print('You have selected a pass heavy strategy')
        return hevpass
    else:
        print('')
        print("Please select a valid option")
        print('')
        phil_choice()
```

```
def callplay():
    global down
    global distance
    global ytg
    print("1) Run")
    print("2) Pass")
    choice = input("Call a play  ")
    print("")
    if choice == "1":
        down += 1
        **result = random.choice(runodds)**
        print("You gained", result, "yards")
        print("")
        ytg = (ytg - result)
        print("You have ", ytg, "yards to go.")
        print("")
        distance = (distance - result)
        if down == 5 and distance > 0:
            print("Turn Over on downs!! You lose...")
            return
        if ytg <= 0:
            print("Touchdown!!! You Win!")
            return
        if distance > 0:
            print("Down and Distance: ", 'Down:', down, '//',
                'Yards need for 1st down: ', distance)
        else:
            distance = 10
            down = 1
            print('FIRST DOWN!\nDown:', down, '//',
                'Yards needed for 1st down: ', distance)
            print("")
        callplay()
```

I've tried what I know of "class.whatever" and "phil_choice(tried-stuff-here)", but no luck

Comment: either the indentation for the `callplay` function is incorrect or it is a recursive function (calls itself).  Can you please clarify if you meant this ?

Comment: also, if these are the methods of the classes, then one would expect to see the `self` parameter in the function arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Your example was missing some initial definitions of down, distance, yards to go, and so forth, so adding in some sample values, following is a snippet of code that sets up a "main" function which calls your helper functions.

```
import random

# Needed to define these in order to get the program to run

balanced = 50   # 50/50 mix
hevrun   = 70   # 70% run, 30% pass
hevpass  = 30   # 30% run, 70% pass
down     = 1    # Start with a first down
ytg      = 75   # Start at own 25 yard line - 75 yards to go
distance = 10   # Start 1st and 10 yards to go for a first down

def phil_choice():
    print('1) Balanced\n2) Run Heavy\n3) Pass Heavy')
    philo_choice = input('Select a coaching style:  ')
    if philo_choice == '1':
        print('')
        print('You have selected a balanced strategy')
        return balanced
    elif philo_choice == '2':
        print('')
        print('You have selected a run heavy strategy')
        return hevrun
    elif philo_choice == '3':
        print('')
        print('You have selected a pass heavy strategy')
        return hevpass
    else:
        print('')
        print("Please select a valid option")
        print('')
        phil_choice()

def callplay(runodds):
    global down
    global distance
    global ytg
    print("1) Run")
    print("2) Pass")

    while True:
        choice = input("Call a play  ")
        print("")

        if choice == "Q":
            break

        if choice == "1":
            down += 1
            result = random.randrange(runodds)
            print("You gained", result, "yards")
            print("")
            ytg = (ytg - result)
            print("You have ", ytg, "yards to go.")
            print("")
            distance = (distance - result)
            if down == 5 and distance > 0:
                print("Turn Over on downs!! You lose...")
                return
            if ytg <= 0:
                print("Touchdown!!! You Win!")
                return
            if distance > 0:
                print("Down and Distance: ", 'Down:', down, '//',
                    'Yards need for 1st down: ', distance)
            else:
                distance = 10
                down = 1
                print('FIRST DOWN!\nDown:', down, '//',
                    'Yards needed for 1st down: ', distance)
                print("")

        if choice == "2":
            down += 1
            result = random.randrange(100 - runodds)
            print("You gained", result, "yards")
            print("")
            ytg = (ytg - result)
            print("You have ", ytg, "yards to go.")
            print("")
            distance = (distance - result)
            if down == 5 and distance > 0:
                print("Turn Over on downs!! You lose...")
                return
            if ytg <= 0:
                print("Touchdown!!! You Win!")
                return
            if distance > 0:
                print("Down and Distance: ", 'Down:', down, '//',
                    'Yards need for 1st down: ', distance)
            else:
                distance = 10
                down = 1
                print('FIRST DOWN!\nDown:', down, '//',
                    'Yards needed for 1st down: ', distance)
                print("")

def main():
    strategy = phil_choice()
    print("Strategy is", strategy)
    callplay(strategy)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

@Dev:~/Python_Programs/CallPlay$ python3 CallPlay.py 
1) Balanced
2) Run Heavy
3) Pass Heavy
Select a coaching style:  2

You have selected a run heavy strategy
Strategy is 70
1) Run
2) Pass
Call a play  1

You gained 11 yards

You have  64 yards to go.

FIRST DOWN!
Down: 1 // Yards needed for 1st down:  10

Call a play  2

You gained 18 yards

You have  46 yards to go.

FIRST DOWN!
Down: 1 // Yards needed for 1st down:  10

Call a play  1

You gained 52 yards

You have  -6 yards to go.

Touchdown!!! You Win!
```

Give that a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.